# RMAN Restore generates an RMAN-06172

Tags: oracle, rman

First time working with RMAN, and I'm having trouble doing a restore following the backup.  Here's what I'm doing:

```
    C:\>rman target /
```

First, let's start with a `delete backup` just to clear the slate...

Then I run `backup database;`

Result:

```
    Starting backup at 02-NOV-16
    using channel ORA_DISK_1
    channel ORA_DISK_1: starting full datafile backup set
    channel ORA_DISK_1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set
    input datafile file number=00004 name=C:\APP\T4PRO\ORADATA\T4PRO\USERS01.DBF
    input datafile file number=00001 name=C:\APP\T4PRO\ORADATA\T4PRO\SYSTEM01.DBF
    input datafile file number=00002 name=C:\APP\T4PRO\ORADATA\T4PRO\SYSAUX01.DBF
    input datafile file number=00003 name=C:\APP\T4PRO\ORADATA\T4PRO\UNDOTBS01.DBF
    channel ORA_DISK_1: starting piece 1 at 02-NOV-16
    channel ORA_DISK_1: finished piece 1 at 02-NOV-16
    piece handle=C:\APP\T4PRO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\T4PRO\BACKUPSET\2016_11_02\O1_MF_NNNDF_TAG20161102T123933_D1N5P643_.BKP tag=TAG20161102T123933 comment=NONE
    channel ORA_DISK_1: backup set complete, elapsed time: 00:00:25
    channel ORA_DISK_1: starting full datafile backup set
    channel ORA_DISK_1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set
    including current control file in backup set
    including current SPFILE in backup set
    channel ORA_DISK_1: starting piece 1 at 02-NOV-16
    channel ORA_DISK_1: finished piece 1 at 02-NOV-16
    piece handle=C:\APP\T4PRO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\T4PRO\BACKUPSET\2016_11_02\O1_MF_NCSNF_TAG20161102T123933_D1N5Q047_.BKP tag=TAG20161102T123933 comment=NONE
    channel ORA_DISK_1: backup set complete, elapsed time: 00:00:01
    Finished backup at 02-NOV-16
```

So far so good.  Do a `list backup` and I get this:

```
    List of Backup Sets
    ===================


    BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
    ------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
    11      Full    5.28G      DISK        00:00:22     02-NOV-16
            BP Key: 11   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TAG20161102T123933
            Piece Name: C:\APP\T4PRO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\T4PRO\BACKUPSET\2016_11_02\O1_MF_NNNDF_TAG20161102T123933_D1N5P643_.BKP
      List of Datafiles in backup set 11
      File LV Type Ckp SCN    Ckp Time  Name
      ---- -- ---- ---------- --------- ----
      1       Full 1474154    02-NOV-16 C:\APP\T4PRO\ORADATA\T4PRO\SYSTEM01.DBF
      2       Full 1474154    02-NOV-16 C:\APP\T4PRO\ORADATA\T4PRO\SYSAUX01.DBF
      3       Full 1474154    02-NOV-16 C:\APP\T4PRO\ORADATA\T4PRO\UNDOTBS01.DBF
      4       Full 1474154    02-NOV-16 C:\APP\T4PRO\ORADATA\T4PRO\USERS01.DBF

    BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
    ------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
    12      Full    9.36M      DISK        00:00:01     02-NOV-16
            BP Key: 12   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TAG20161102T123933
            Piece Name: C:\APP\T4PRO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\T4PRO\BACKUPSET\2016_11_02\O1_MF_NCSNF_TAG20161102T123933_D1N5Q047_.BKP
      SPFILE Included: Modification time: 02-NOV-16
      SPFILE db_unique_name: T4PRO
      Control File Included: Ckp SCN: 1474163      Ckp time: 02-NOV-16
```

So everything here looks fine. My control file as I understand it is this `O1_MF_NCSNF_TAG20161102T123933_D1N5Q047_.BKP` file.  So next I want to do a restore of the db from RMAN:

```
    RMAN> shutdown immediate

    database closed
    database dismounted
    Oracle instance shut down

    RMAN> startup nomount

    connected to target database (not started)
    Oracle instance started

    Total System Global Area    6797832192 bytes

    Fixed Size                     2188648 bytes
    Variable Size               3556772504 bytes
    Database Buffers            3221225472 bytes
    Redo Buffers                  17645568 bytes
```

And here's where I get the problem:

```
    RMAN> restore controlfile from 'O1_MF_NCSNF_TAG20161102T123933_D1N5Q047_.BKP';

    Starting restore at 02-NOV-16
    allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
    channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=63 device type=DISK

    channel ORA_DISK_1: no AUTOBACKUP in 7 days found
    RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
    RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
    RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
    RMAN-03002: failure of restore command at 11/02/2016 12:50:25
    RMAN-06172: no AUTOBACKUP found or specified handle is not a valid copy or piece
```

I've tried a few different controlfile parameters but none seem to work.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you need the full path to the piece, `from 'C:\APP\T4PRO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\T4PRO\BACKUPSET\2016_11_02\O1_MF_NCSNF_TAG20161102T123933_D1N5Q047_.BKP'`? Is that one of the parameters you've tried?

Comment: That's it. Solved!  Looking back at the instructions they were operating in the directory where the backups were, so they didn't need it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RMAN expects you to provide the full path to the specified handle, in your case would be the full path to 'O1_MF_NCSNF_TAG20161102T123933_D1N5Q047_.BKP'.

In your particular case this would be:

> C:\APP\T4PRO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\T4PRO\BACKUPSET\2016_11_02‌​\O1_MF_NCSNF_TAG20161102T123933_D1N5Q047_.BKP

By default RMAN would look for the file at the FRA (Fast Recovery Area) which is the same location given by parameter 'db_recovery_file_dest'.